# Spring Boot Test. @DirtiesContext annotation closes HikariPool

Tags: spring-boot, liquibase, spring-boot-test

I am slapping `@DirtiesContext` annotation on my integration tests as I want the application context to get rebuilt from scratch.
But, this closed the JDBC pool and my Liquibase bean cannot be created.
Pls, see logs for details.
Any idea how to fix this?

```
2021-03-29 18:17:28.799  WARN [] 25836 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
2021-03-29 18:17:29.992 ERROR [] 25836 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: java.sql.SQLException: HikariDataSource HikariDataSource (HikariPool-1) has been closed.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1794)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:516)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
```

Comment: By not using `@DirtiesContext` as that will close/destsroy beans and do a refresh. Do you really need `@DirtiesContext`?

Comment: The reason I started using @ DirtiesContext b/c I see that I have multiple scheduler tasks of the same nature being launched, whereas my tests rely only on one scheduled task running at all times, @ DirtiesContext seemingly solves this problem. Even though it slows down tests drastically.

Comment: Which seems to wrong tool to fix this. Why are there even multiple tasks scheduled. Do you use `@SpringBootTest` for tests that don't really need it? Do you use `@SpringBootTest` on different tests with different combinations of `@MockBean` instances?

Comment: I need those @ SpringBootTest annotations on every test class as I am testing my app via REST layer and then there is a separation based on the functional area.
I do not use @ MockBean, but I do have plenty of @SpyBeans sprinkled across my ITs. Could this be a contributing factor?

Comment: Yes, because each unique combination of `@SpringBootTest`/`@SpyBean` will result in a new application being started. So if you have 3 tests with each a different `@SpyBean` it will start the app 3 times, resulting in multiple listeners in your case.

Comment: Where would you recommend pushing those spy beans? Maybe in the common `@TestConfiguration` class? What are the best practices under such circumstances? 
I want app to get started only once over the course of testing and then I need to do some spying/mocking in some of those ITs?